# Java regex match same length groups

Tags: java, regex

I want to match strings like
(()) - 2 open brackets, 2 closed brackets
but not strings like
()() - open and closed and then another opens and closses
(() - two opens, one closed

So more specific i want a regex like this

```
\({n}\){n}
```

n opened brackets followed by (same value for n, but n must be greedy) n closed brackets.

Comment: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ePxoe7/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's a shame it's still called regular expression...

Comment: @xenteros: [You don't say so :)](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%28%29%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%3co%3e%29%5c%28%7c%28%3f%3c-o%3e%29%5c%29%29*%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%29%5c%29&i=%28%28%29%29%0d%0a%28%28%29%0d%0a%28%29%28%29)

Comment: Regex should represent regular language. The above isn't regular.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew